# Media queries & JqueryMobile - which one to choose?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

Our goal is to create a website which works on mobile devices as well.
I guess a pretty generic requirement.

I've read about the media queries & I've dabbled into Jquery-Mobile as well.

**Here is what I understand**

- Jquery Mobile seems geared for mobile devices only.
- And the media queries tells me what the device is and what CSS to apply - but doesn't give me all the goodies from Jquery-Mobile. I don't want to re-invent the wheel and do what JM has done.

**So the questions are**

- So which one should I choose ?!
- Or is there a way to combine them ?
- What is the standard (or is there one.. ?)

Comment: jQuery Mobile also works on desktop browsers, with or without touch capability.

Comment: I know, but the site isn't very desktop like.. what I'd rather have is when someone visits the site from a mobile device the Jquery code kick in.

Answer (score 3):

I will keep this rather general: my point of view is that jQuery mobile & responsive layout are two completely different approaches.
Besides **jQuery mobile** being responsive (in terms of adapting to the screen dimensions), it comes with a massive overhead. You had to adjust your site structure to match the jQuery conventions if you wanted to take advantage of its features, so it would basically be a "second website". It is not just adding the script. Moreover, styling takes a lot more effort, as jQuery mobile adds its own markup to the page, which is often nested and adds around 10 css classes to elements. Having said that, if you are using a CMS (like Wordpress, for example) and have lots of data-driven content like a blog, the experience could be a lot better with jQuery mobile.
There are some plugins that turn your blog into a mobile page with the flick of a switch...

If you wanted to preserve your websites look and it would be perfectly alright to scale the images, change the fontsize and add a bit of padding here and there, I would be going for **responsive layout**. It definitely would take some effort too, especially if you have not implemented it from the beginning (mobile first to add a buzzword here), but it would be a "lightweight" approach to address mobile devices. Another thing is that responsive layout works at "runtime" on any device, so if you scaled your browser window, it would adapt to the changes in realtime. You could change your layout seamlessly to adapt to different screen sizes, let's say "mobile phone", "tablet" and "desktop". With "fluid grids" you could change a three column layout on a desktop to a two-column layout on tablets and a single-column layout on mobiles. For jQuery mobile to kick in on mobile websites only, you would have to perform some more or less reliable checks when your user enters the page, just to redirect him/her.

So, don't get me wrong, I have used jQuery mobile on many "designed for mobile" pages and/or apps (often in combination with Phonegap), and I kind of like it besides being somewhat slow.
If you want to optimize your website for mobile devices, however, responsive layouts might be the easiest way to achieve that.

By the way, that is basically what Jeff Powers recommends, just a bit more "Techie" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You get the biggest bang for your buck by using relative units. Use percentages for width's, padding, etc. Then use em's for all font sizes, icons and padding that you want to be relative to font sizes. Then you can use media queries to make small changes that need to be done along the way from small to large viewport sizes. What's nice about this approach is that site remains fluid so it will automatically adjust most of it's components to the viewport size and save you some work.

For a more in depth look check out this post.
http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids

And try working from mobile layout up otherwise you will find yourself undoing and redoing styles instead of just adding to what you already have.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. But this doesn't answer the question of how do we use the features in Jquery-Mobile.